# RSUBMIT Parallel SAS RUN

Tags: sas

I am currently using the SAS enterprise guide 8.3 and test the Parallel runs with RSUBMIT function using the code below. The log does not give any error, but the dataset (sillya.part1  and sillya.part1) created by the code are empty. Anybody know why? thanks a ton!

```
options autosignon sascmd='!sascmd -nosyntaxcheck';

libname sillya "/sasnas/conscreditriskmodeling/CONSMODL/E468/Test" ;
libname sillyb "/sasnas/conscreditriskmodeling/CONSMODL/E468/Test/Hai" ;

rsubmit process=task1 wait=no inheritlib=(sillya) ;
libname sillya "/sasnas/conscreditriskmodeling/CONSMODL/E468/Test" ;
data sillya.part1 (keep=str);
  length str $1000;
  do i=1 to 11;
     str = '';
     do j=1 to 10;
        str = cats(str,'A');
     end;
     output;
  end;
run;
endrsubmit;


rsubmit process=task2 wait=no inheritlib=(sillyb) ;
libname sillyb "/sasnas/conscreditriskmodeling/CONSMODL/E468/Test/Hai" ;
data sillyb.part2 (keep=str);
  length str $1000;
  do i=1 to 7;
     str = '';
     do j=1 to 10;
        str = cats(str,'B');
     end;
     output;
  end;
run;
endrsubmit;


waitfor _all_ task1 task2;


data merge_1_2 ;
set sillya.part1 sillyb.part2 ;

run;
```

Comment: Why are you replacing the libref you defined with the INHERITLIB= option in the remote code?  Either remove the inheritlib= option or remove the libname statement.

Comment: Thank you so much Tom! it works now. Do you know why i have INHERITLIB= option and libname statement together, the code breaks down?

Answer (score 1):

The INHERITLIB= option is used to create a libref on the REMOTE session that points to a libref that already exists in the LOCAL session.

So if you then add a separate LIBNAME statement on the remote side using the same libref that will override that definition.

At best it is redundant to define the same libref twice.

At worst the remote session is running on a different server so that it does not have access to the path on the local server where you want to write the new dataset.

If the idea is to make the data available to the LOCAL session then remove the remote LIBNAME statements.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you so much Tom!